# Cartesian product $G \times H$ is a Lie group

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G $ and $H $ be two Lie groups. Prove that the cartesian product $G \times H$ is a Lie group.

By definition a Lie group is a differentiable manifold with a differentiable operation:

$$G \times G \rightarrow\mathbb\ G$$

$$(g_1,g_2)\rightarrow\mathbb\ g_1g_2^{-1}$$

So I tried with:

$$(G \times H)\times (G \times H) \rightarrow\mathbb\ G \times H$$

$$((g_1,h_1), (g_2,h_2))\rightarrow\mathbb\ (g_1h_1)(g_2h_2)^{-1}$$

But I don't know how to conclude that it is a Lie group.

Comment: What do you mean by $g_1 h_1$ or $g_2 h_2$? How is $(g_1h_1)(g_2h_2)^{-1}$ an element of $G \times H$?

Comment: @AlexProvost That is the question, the way I concluded that seems logic to me but I don’t understand how to interpret that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question:** "I don't know how to conclude that it is a Lie group."

**Answer:** If $m_G:G\times G \rightarrow G, m_H:H\times H \rightarrow H$ are the addition operations and $u:G\rightarrow G, u(g):=g^{-1}, v: H \rightarrow H, v(h):=h^{-1}$ are the inversions,
it follows $m_G, m_H, u,v$ are smooth maps. The product $G\times H$ is a smooth manifold and the product map

$$m:G\times H \times G \times H \rightarrow G \times H$$

with $m((g,h), (g',h')):=(gg',hh')$ and inversion map $w(g,h):=(g^{-1}, h^{-1})$
are smooth maps. It follows $(G\times H,m,w)$ is a smooth manifold with idenitity $(e_G,e_H)$.